# Creating a test suite with Spring test

Tags: java, spring, junit4, spring-test

In my Spring-Maven project my unit tests inherit from a base class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:testDalApplicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional(value = "transactionManager")
public abstract class BaseRepositoryUnitTest {

}
```

Then a tipical unit test can look like:

```
public class UserRepositoryTest extends BaseRepositoryUnitTest {

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Test
public void testFindUserByEmailAddress() {
 ...
}
}
```

This structure allows me to:

- Run a single test as a Junit test (from my Eclipse IDE).
- Run all my tests using Maven build.

How do I run all my tests from my Eclipse IDE? I know I should create a test suite, but for some reason with this structure I can't seem to figure out how.

BTW - I'm using Junit 4.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To run all of the Junit tests within your application**

Right click the Project or Package > Run as > Junit Test

[image]

Comment: @forhas I just tested this scenario in my local STS, seems to work.  Did you have any luck?

Comment: @forhas Excellent, I battled this one also in the past, glad I could help someone out.

Answer (score -2):

mvn -Dtest=TestCircle test

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Another way to run a particular test case where TestCircle is the file number and test is the method name.